# Setting a combobox to update a textbox in Visual Studio, c#, Microsoft Blend, XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, visual-studio-2015

I am switching over a program from Access to C# in visual studio 2015 using Microsoft Blend. In short I have a combobox labeled cb_Address. It is bound to a field called "address: from a database called "orderheader" in XAML via:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,158.71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource orderheaderTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/dataroot/orderheader}">
```

That populates the address combo box (user can now use the dropdown menu to select a record, although it's populating the box with an incremental record value rather than the addy itself, I need to fix that later.)  In the event that a user selects a record I'd like it to update a textbox on the same page called tb_Address with the address field from the orderheader db.

In access that would be something like:

```
Sub cb_Address_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo e1
DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "[auto] = " & Me![cb_Address]
Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
e1:
End Sub
```

As of yet I haven't found a clear tutorial on how to do the event handler with this Blend/c# environment. My best guess is to use SelectionChanged like

```
 private void cb_Address_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

but being new to c# I haven't found the code to update the tb_Address textbox. I was playing around with

```
cb_AddressItem cbi = ((sender as cb_Address).SelectedItem as Lcb_AddressItem);
```

But I'm at a loss for how to continue. Any help is appreciated!

---

**Edit 1:** As per the suggestion below, I now have this heading my window XAML

```
<Window x:Class="CC_Ticketing_WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CC_Ticketing_WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="600">
```

and this as my combobox and text box respectively:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,158.71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource orderheaderTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/dataroot/orderheader}" SelectedValuePath="Content">

<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,214,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35.824" Width="154" FontSize="21.333" FontFamily="Adobe Arabic" Text="{Binding ElementName=cb_Address,Path=SelectedItem.Content,Mode=OneWay}">
```

Unfortunately selecting a record from the combo box still only populates itself with a numerical number and the textbox with nothing. I tried replacing "Content" with "address" in both snippits in case it the direct database label but that provided the same result.

---

**EDIT 2:**

The locations of any instance of "orderheaderTemplate."

in MainWindow.xaml, just under the xmlns declarations:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="orderheaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=address}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="orderheaderTemplate1">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=address}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

In App.xaml, just under the xmlns declarations:

```
<Application.Resources>

        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="orderheaderDataSource" Source="C:\Users\User\Desktop\C#_Ticketing\orderheader.xml" d:IsDataSource="True"/>

</Application.Resources>
```

In the Resources window:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22083389/Xdata2.png

---

**Edit 3**

Recap: In the simplest terms: I created an xml data source in Visual Studio 2015 Blend. I named that xml Datasource orderheaderDatasource and linked it to my database which is in turn named orderheader.  That xml orderheader database has many records, each with several fields like address, city, fname, lname, etc.

All I need to accomplish is for a combobox to populate itself with the address fields of every record, then when the user selects one, send that address field to a textbox.

The Entire clean slate Xaml at this point after backtracking:

```
<Window x:Class="CC_Ticketing_WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CC_Ticketing_WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="orderheaderDataSource" XPath="/Info">
            <x:XData>
                <Info xmlns="">
                    <Order ID="001" Address="Example 1" />
                    <Order ID="002" Address="Example 2" />
                    <Order ID="003" Address="Example 2" />
                </Info>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" DataContext="{StaticResource orderheaderDataSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Order}" DisplayMemberPath="@Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Address" Text="{Binding ElementName=cb_Address,Path=Text}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

All this does currently is populate the combobox with 
Example 1
Example 2
Example 3
and upon selecting it does send to the textbox.

Every effort to link the combobox to orderheader's "address" field then send it to the textbox has failed. I *can* get the combobox to populate the addresses from orderheader correctly with some of the early code, but that's it. Nothing has ever sent the address to the textbox upon selecting, which after a week of trying and Cadogi's good help has sent me spiraling into a void of insanity and disbelief in the wake of XAML's apparent hateful nature for first timers.

---

**Final Edit | Working Code**

```
<Window x:Class="CC_Ticketing_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CC_Ticketing_WPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="orderheaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=address}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" DataContext="{StaticResource orderheaderDataSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/dataroot/orderheader/address}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Address" Text="{Binding ElementName=cb_Address,Path=Text}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: How about tb_Adress.Value = cb_Address.Text or cb_Address.Value?

Comment: All your data is in a database already broken down into business models?! This is a perfect situation to apply MVVM and design your application correctly.  That being said, you would need no use for code-behind.  Just a thought.

Comment: Address.Value and .Text are throwing exceptions as if cb_Address and tb_Address don't exist in xaml.

Comment: I'd be interested to do it in MVVM but I don't know where to start there, looking through documents now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just keep this in the XAML to keep it nice and clean-

in your combo box add SelectedValuePath property:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,158.71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource orderheaderTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/dataroot/orderheader}" SelectedValuePath="Content" />
```

This should tell the combobox where to look when requesting a value.

in your textbox bind the Text to the combobox selected value:

```
<Textbox x:Name="tb_Address" Text="{Binding ElementName=cb_Address,Path=SelectedItem.Content,Mode=OneWay}" />
```

---

**Edit below**

Could you try the code below instead of what you have / or start a new project to test this. Ignore the DataContext just have this inside your initial grid.:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,158.71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True"  SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Address Example 1"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Address Example 2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Address Example 3"/>
</ComboBox>

 <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,214,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35.824" Width="154" FontSize="21.333" FontFamily="Adobe Arabic" Text="{Binding ElementName=cb_Address,Path=SelectedItem.Content,Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

This should definitely work, if it does then I would assume both issues you are having are due to the ItemTemplate you are using. Make sure orderheaderTemplate is binding your display data (address) from orderheader to the orderheaderTemplate Content property.

---

**Edit 2 redo**

This example should allow you to achieve the desired result - I have now built a project in order to test this. I have also built the XmlDataProvider in so you can see how its working.

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <!-- simple data example -->
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="orderheaderDataSource" XPath="/Info">
        <x:XData>
            <Info xmlns="">
<!-- these are basically the rows of your actual data source -->
                <Order ID="001" Address="Example 1" City="New York" fname="John" lname="Smith" />
                <Order ID="002" Address="Example 2" City="London" fname="Jane" lname="Doe" />
                <Order ID="003" Address="Example 3" City="Paris" fname="Joe" lname="Bloggs" />
            </Info>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>    
    <StackPanel>
<!-- combo to be replaced with your working example -->
        <ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" DataContext="{StaticResource orderheaderDataSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Order}" DisplayMemberPath="@Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True"/>
<!-- textblock shows what is being displayed in the combo -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Address" Text="{Binding ElementName=cb_Address,Path=Text}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

You will need to swap out the binding information to match your data source. But this should let you play around to see what the properties are doing.

I believe you got the combo to display properly using the below (this just skips a couple of the properties from the example):

```
ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/dataroot/orderheader/address}
```

This makes the DataContext and DisplayMemberPath redundant as you are pointing straight to the address.

**Using the above code**

```
<Window x:Class="CC_Ticketing_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CC_Ticketing_WPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="600">
<StackPanel>
<!-- I think this what you said populated properly in the comments -->
    <ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/dataroot/orderheader/address}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True"/>
<!-- this should replicate what you see in the combobox -->
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Address" Text="{Binding ElementName=cb_Address,Path=Text}"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This should work based on the feedback you have given it's very basic, and will limit how you can present that data if you want to use a template or any multi-bindings. Hopefully it will work for you as is.

What you have done on your own was skip the *DisplayMemberPath* from my last post by using "/address" in the ItemsSource property in your ComboBox.
Then the text is being bound in the TextBlock to the Text Property of your ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I feel like this is the track I need to be on.  I posted an edit at the bottom of my question with what I replaced but it hasn't changed the outcome yet. If it helps to know the process, in blend I created an xml data source from the "orderheader" db, and dragged the address: (String) label onto the cb_Address combobox to create my initial code.  That allows me to search address record but the box itself populates with just an incremental reference number once I select an address.  Nothing I have tried yet sends any information to tb_Address.

Comment: Your edit definitely does work. I've gone back to what you originally suggested and I'm looking for what is wrong in the binding.  Here is a picture: http://tinyurl.com/nljgtt8  To get the data in I just hit the green + for create XML data source,  named it orderheaderTemplate, and you can see the orderheader database and its fields imported. Where should I look to check the relationship between orderheaderTemplate, orderheader itself, and address?  It seems like it's all set up already..

Comment: In your ComboBox you have a property as follows:
ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource orderheaderTemplate}".  

You need to find that style (orderheaderTemplate) - in either MainWindow.xaml, app.xaml or a ResoureseDictionary if you have any. Then check that for your databinding

Comment: Above should be *ResourceDictionary* - I ran out of time to edit

Comment: In Edit 2 above I have placed every instance I can find of orderheaderTemplate.  I apologize for the additional questions, I'm really grateful for your ongoing help. I am still at a loss for what exactly to change to correct this. No binding documentation I've come across has clarified what I'm missing here.

Comment: Also of note, in the combobox if I completely remove: --  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource orderheaderTemplate}" --  and then add address to -- ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/dataroot/orderheader/address}" -- it now at least updates the combobox itself with the address instead of numerical record value, but it still sends nothing to the textbox.

Comment: Same result with your second edit.  This thing just will not send to the textbox  XD

Comment: The code in edit 3 should send the text to the textblock. If not then please show the binding error you are getting. The XmlDataProvider in that example is only there to simulate your data source to help you understand what is happening with it. You can remove it and put the ComboBox back to how you had it when in was showing the addresses properly.

Comment: have you had any success changing the data source from the example back to your datatable?

Comment: Negative. As I said, the code in Edit 3 works, but I straight up don't know how to change that code suggested into one that uses my database, that's why I wrote out how I implemented my database and how everything was named in case you had thoughts on that since none of the earlier methods worked. Manually insert the list: yes.  Use a linked database: no.

Comment: Success! Finnaally, my lord, awesome.  That final code you provided didn't populate the combobox but things started working properly once I added this to the combobox: |  DataContext="{StaticResource orderheaderDataSource}"  |  I'll edit in the final working code and finally checkmark this as solved.  Thanks a ton for your help Cadogi!

Comment: And I think I see what you were saying earlier, it also works correctly if I use: |  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/dataroot/orderheader}" DisplayMemberPath="address"  |  Does using this method make it less limited for multiple bindings in the future?

Comment: Glad you've got it working! Also that you sorted out the DataContext. To answer your question, No the DisplayMemberPath won't allow MultiBinding, it only points to the location of your info. It will mean that down the line your ItemsSource won't be limited to just the Address property. So if you were to implement a DataTemplate again then you can format it however you like - usually I would use Runs in a scenario like this to show the individual address lines etc. in one textblock.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively You can solve as in your origional post:

XAML: (in your combobox)

```
SelectionChanged="cb_Address_SelectionChanged"
```

C#:

```
private void cb_Address_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
tb_Address.Text = ((ComboBoxItem)cb_Address.SelectedItem).Content.ToString;
}
```

Assuming The pure XAML approach continues to fail.

Comment: This is promising... I think ToString; was supposed to be ToString(); , correct?  Without it the app didn't compile.  Once I ran it the addresses did load in the combobox but upon selecting a record the program breaks and throws this error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22083389/Xdata3.png

Comment: Additional info: If I change that method to just see what's passing  [ ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;  and  MessageBox.Show(cb.SelectedValue.ToString());  ] It returns the exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: You are correct it should have been ToString(). I have posted a final example for you above which should be enough for you to get this working using only XAML - as I do think its much cleaner.

Comment: In edit2 redo....yes that works but again it limits me to having to enter every record manually in the place of example 1, 2, 3.....I need it to read out of the db which is thousands of records long. You said to swap out my binding but the way it's currently presented I don't know what you mean beyond adhering to that format and inserting every record manually in the <info tag which just isn't going to happen. Either I'm missing something fundamental or XAML makes it waaay too convoluted to do something as simple as load a db field into a combobox and send the selection to a textbox :/

Comment: I put a 3rd and final edit up with from scratch code using your current template.